# How to limit the picture size to a specified dimension in a picture box when saving in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would be glad if someone could very kindly show me how I can limit the picture size to a specified dimension (e.g 150  by 200 pixels) when saving. An error message should indicate the required dimension if it is not met.

However, the following is the code to upload the picture into a picture box.

```
Private Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Try
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        img = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Size.Width > 150 Or Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Size.Height > 200 Then 
   lblPhotoErr.Text = "More than 150 x 200"
   bError = True
End If
```